# brew postinstall python (2.7.13): [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I am on OS X 10.11.6. I updated and upgraded brew today. After that, `pip` did not work. It looked as if it was not installed during the upgrade. When I finished the upgrade I saw the warning:

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully You can try again using brew postinstall python
```

So I ran `brew postinstall python` and I then encountered the error:

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py'
```

In [this](https://superuser.com/questions/915810/pip-not-working-on-hombrew-python-2-7-install) post they say:

> The post-install step did not complete successfully due to `error: could not delete '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py': Permission denied.` Manually deleting that file and then running brew postinstall python again fixed it.

So I thought the fix would be the same and I manually deleted `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py'` so that

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/
_vendor extern
```

I ran `brew postinstall python` again but now I obtain:

```
...
copying build/lib/easy_install.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
copying build/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py'`
```

I found "a fix" by installing pip using `easy_install`:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

And now everything seems to work fine. However, I have two questions:

1. Have I messed up by manually removing `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py'`?
2. What would be the fix for the `[Errno 13] Permission denied` when `brew postinstall python`?

---

In case it is of any use, here is my `brew config` and `brew doctor` outputs after all that happened today:

```
$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.1.6
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 619791e83d2781dca1b675e20249a8aebe085c7c
Last commit: 6 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 5ce01ec9c8b9958e2d9a7791e4d4e2aa0bf4fd8f
Core tap last commit: 89 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.0.0-p648
Clang: 8.0 build 800
Git: 2.10.1 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_91
macOS: 10.11.6-x86_64
Xcode: 8.2.1
CLT: 8.2.0.0.1.1480973914
X11: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11

$ brew doctor
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
  /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
  /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
  /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
  /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
  /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/tcl.h
  /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
  /usr/local/include/tk.h
  /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
  /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest method I've found to fix this is to simply set the ownership of the folder to your username:

```
chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Edit:  On occasion, I also run this:

```
sudo -H python3 -m pip install ...
```

or

```
sudo -H pip install
```

Comment: as simple as that (facepalm). It worked. MANY THANKS